# Vue algolia autosuggest on select showing [Object object]

Tags: vue.js, algolia

#### TLDR

How can i set the value of `vue-autosuggest` after clicking on a suggestion?

I have a relatively simple app that I am using [ais-instasearch](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/autocomplete/vue/) along with [vue-autosuggest](https://github.com/darrenjennings/vue-autosuggest). My app is working as expected, but that issue I am having is that when I select an item from the suggestions, it is setting my input field to `[Object object]`, and I cant figure out from the docs, nor from debugging what value I should return so that I can clear out the input field. As far as my code, the inout box is not mapping to any `v-model`s.

When I inspect the values set, for example i search for `lol`, I see that `ais-autoComplete` component has the value `lol` in its state.

My component is

```
<ais-instant-search :search-client="searchClient" index-name="blogs">
    <ais-configure
        :hitsPerPage="showing"
        :restrictSearchableAttributes="searchCategories"
    />
    <ais-autocomplete :classNames="{'ais-Autocomplete': 'tools-searchbar'}">
        <template slot-scope="{ currentRefinement, indices, refine }">
            <vue-autosuggest
                :suggestions="indicesToSuggestions(indices)"
                @selected="onSelect"
                :input-props="{
                          id: 'tools-searchbar',
                          onInputChange: refine,
                          placeholder: 'Search for blogs...',
                        }"
            >
                <template slot-scope="{ suggestion }">
                    <a id="tools-link" target="_blank">
                        <v-flex>
                            <v-avatar class="pr-2" size="36">
                                <img
                                    :src="suggestion.item.image || '/blogs.png'"
                                    alt="/blogs.png"
                                />
                            </v-avatar>
                            <span id="tool-name">
                                <ais-highlight
                                    :hit="suggestion.item"
                                    attribute="resolved_title"
                                    v-if="suggestion.item.resolved_title"
                                />
                            </span>
                            <div id="tool-description">
                                <ais-highlight
                                    :hit="suggestion.item"
                                    attribute="excerpt"
                                    v-if="suggestion.item.excerpt"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </v-flex>
                    </a>
                </template>
            </vue-autosuggest>
        </template>
    </ais-autocomplete>
</ais-instant-search>
```

And my methods are:

```
methods: {
    onSelect(selected) {
      if (selected) {
        this.query = "";
        window.open(selected.item.resolved_url);
      }
    },
    indicesToSuggestions(indices) {
      if (this.loggedin) {
        return indices.map(({ hits }) => ({ data: hits }));
      }
    },
```

The first image is before clicking on the matched result. 
[image: Before clicking on the matched results]

The second image is after clicking on the matched result. 
[image: After click on the matched result]

This is showing the component with the value of `lol` after clicking
[image]

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No, still havnt solved it.

Comment: i have same issue with if exist value on v-model then we select again, the output would like that `object-object` but in render html when show on `span` its not an object , its a string ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Vue-autosuggest docs:

https://github.com/darrenjennings/vue-autosuggest#getsuggestionvalue

Use the prop get-suggestion-value and bind a method to return whatever attribute you want from that suggestion.

```
 <vue-autosuggest
    v-model="query"
    :suggestions="filteredOptions"
    @focus="focusMe"
    @click="clickHandler"
    @input="onInputChange"
    @selected="onSelected"
    :get-suggestion-value="getSuggestionValue"
    :input-props="{id:'autosuggest__input', placeholder:'Do you feel lucky, punk?'}">
    <div slot-scope="{suggestion}" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
      <img :style="{ display: 'flex', width: '25px', height: '25px', borderRadius: '15px', marginRight: '10px'}" :src="suggestion.item.avatar" />
      <div style="{ display: 'flex', color: 'navyblue'}">{{suggestion.item.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </vue-autosuggest>
```

and,

```
getSuggestionValue(suggestion) {
  return suggestion.item.name;
},
```