# vue-autosuggest output object-object on twice click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autosuggest

by the way this question very similar on [Vue algolia autosuggest on select showing [Object object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367720/vue-algolia-autosuggest-on-select-showing-object-object)

but i still did not solve here is my debug or code

```
<b-form-group
                label="Name Agen"
                label-for="vi-agen-name"
              >
                <span v-text="form.agen.name_agen" />
                <vue-autosuggest
                  id="vi-agen-name"
                  v-model="form.agen.name_agen"
                  :suggestions="[{ data: form.agen.agens }]"
                  :limit="7"
                  :input-props="{
                    id: 'autosuggest__input',
                    class: 'form-control',
                    placeholder: 'Name Agen',
                  }"
                  @selected="onSelectedFrom"
                  @input="searchForm($event, 'agen/', 'agen', 'name_agen')"
                >
                  <template slot-scope="{suggestion}">
                    <span class="my-suggestion-item">{{ suggestion.item.name_agen }}</span>
                  </template>
                </vue-autosuggest>
              </b-form-group>
```

my problem:

1. i have on typing `yogi` on `form input`
2. select item that show on suggesstion : `[ { data : [ { name_agen : 'Yogi' .....`

`<span v-text="form.agen.name_agen" />` // output : Yogi

`form input` // output : yogi

but when i tried to type again on `form input`   `yogiabc`
thats not show any suggestion so i remove by backspace so the input now is `yogi`

then i tried `select again`

the unexpected on twice select :

`<span v-text="form.agen.name_agen" />` // output : Yogi // why this **result is string**

`form input` // output : `object-object` // but on **form input is an object-object ?**

function code:

```
async onSelectedFrom(option) {
      const model = this.form.currentModel
      const fieldSuggest = this.form.currentFieldSuggest
      const currentLoadData = this.form[`${model}`][`${model}s`]

      const currentField = this.form[`${model}`][`${fieldSuggest}`]
      this.form[`${model}`] = {
        isNew: false,
        [`${model}s`]: currentLoadData,
        ...option.item,
      }
      console.log('selected', this.form[`${model}`], 'Name Agen:', currentField)
    },
    searchForm(keyword, uri, model, currentSuggest) {
      this.form.currentModel = model
      this.form.currentFieldSuggest = currentSuggest
      if (keyword) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutDebounce)
        this.timeoutDebounce = setTimeout(() => {
          useJwt.http.get(`${uri}`, { params: { keyword, single_search: true } })
            .then(response => {
// test debug
              if (response.data.total_items === 0) {
                // no data
                this.form[`${model}`].isNew = true
                this.form[`${model}`].user.full_name = null
                this.form.isAgenAndTrans = false
                this.form[`${model}`][`${model}s`] = []
                console.log('no data show', this.form[`${model}`])
              } else {
                // this.form[`${model}`].isNew = false
                this.form.isAgenAndTrans = false
                this.form[`${model}`][`${model}s`] = response.data[`${model}s`]
              }
            }).catch(e => {
              this.form[`${model}`].isNew = true
              this.form[`${model}`].user.full_name = null
              this.form.isAgenAndTrans = false
              this.form[`${model}`][`${model}s`] = []
            })
        }, 300)
      }
    },
```

then these the **data**

```
  data() {
    return {
      payload: [],
      form: {
        currentModel: '',
        currentFieldSuggest: '',
        isAgenAndTrans: false,
        agen: {
          isNew: true,
          id: 0,
          name_agen: '',
          dm_personal_id: 0,
          user: {
            full_name: '',
          },
          agens: [],
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you haven't shown your JS code, an you haven't tried `:get-suggestion-value` as in the answer you LINKED TO

Comment: ah my bad, i have already modified my question with function code

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX i have solved with the properties i miss on code, thanks so much